# Unpivot Transformation Error: XX column is not of the same unpivot datatype (Data flow in ADF)

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to unpivot the following data table, but I got the error: **KPI1 column is not of the same unpivot datatype**. I checked the KPI1 datatype. It is a long format. I think it is one type of numerical datatypes (integer, decimal, long, double, etc), all numerical columns should be treated in the same way.

[image]

Thank you for any insights to fix the error.

Comment: Can you show us any screenshots of your data flow unpivot steps?

Comment: Hi Leon, Finally I fixed it by ensuring all numerical variables have the same datatypes - double. It seems that I cannot mix different numerical formats when I want to unpivot the data table. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I fixed it by changing the datatypes of other numerical columns.

[image]

If you have multiple numerical datatypes, it is hard to define the datatype of the new numerical unpivoted column.

[image]